# Add terms to anonymous function in for loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add terms to an anonymous function in a for loop.

Isotherm = @(N) log(N)-log(P);

k=0;
for an=a
Isotherm2 = @(N) (1/T)*an*mpower(N,k);
Isotherm = @(N) Isotherm(N) + Isotherm2(N);
k=k+1;
end

k=0;
for bn=b
Isotherm2 = @(N) bn*mpower(N,k);
Isotherm = @(N) Isotherm(N) + Isotherm2(N);
k=k+1;
end

I've tried the preceding code, but it is not working correctly.  Do I need to use an m-file function?

Comment: what's not working?.. more specifically what are you trying to accomplish? Isotherm is acting like a nested function call...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow what you are intending to do. However, if `N` is a scalar value, the following vectorized solution should perform the computation you want:

```
Isotherm = @(N) log(N)-log(P) + ...
                (1/T)*sum(a.*N.^(0:numel(a)-1)) + ...
                sum(b.*N.^(0:numel(b)-1));
```

Incidentally, as much as I **DID NOT** expect the following to work, it actually does:

```
>> f = @(x) x;
>> for i = 2:4, f = @(x) f(x) + x.^i; end    %# f(x) = x + x.^2 + x.^3 + x.^4
>> f(2)

ans =

    30    %# 2 + 4 + 8 + 16

>> f(3)

ans =

   120    %# 3 + 9 + 27 + 81
```

So the way you are adding your anonymous functions may not be the source of your problem, although it is a *very* confusing way to do things and may have some other limitations I have yet to find.

Comment: +1 for finding possibly the least maintainable Matlab coding idiom ever.

Comment: @Andrew: Isn't it **hideous**!? But it works! I guess each time the anonymous function is recreated in the loop the old anonymous function `f` gets captured and held constant at its current value just like any other non-argument variable in an anonymous expression does. I wonder if there are any limitations to this, like increasing memory usage in order to store the "frozen" anonymous functions.